# transferring the same images logic to another file

Tags: qml

Is it possible to transfer the same code logic in another page, in which these two images are taken as alias or something similar and they behave in the same pattern of "if statement" logic on the other QML file(2) when this button is pressed from the first QML file(1)?

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Studio.Components 1.0
import QtQuick.Timeline 1.0

Item {
id: root
width: 500
height: 500
property alias locking: locking

    Text {
        id: confirmSign
        text: qsTr("")
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top
        font.styleName: "Bold"
        anchors.leftMargin: 70
        anchors.topMargin: 55
        color: "white"
        font.pointSize: 10
        font.family: "Tahoma"
    }
    RoundButton {
        id: locking
        y: 70
        width: 90
        height: 90
        anchors.left: password_field.right
        anchors.leftMargin: 15
        Image {
            id: unlck
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            source: "Images/Unlocked.png"
            visible: false
        }
        Image {
            id: lcked
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            source: "Images/Locked.png"
            visible: true
        }

        onClicked: {
                passBlocker.visible = true
                confirmSign.text = qsTr("The ToolBar is 'Locked' ");
                confirmSign.color = "#ffffff";
                lcked.visible = true
                unlck.visible = false
                 }
             }
            }
```

Comment: Your question is absolute unclear. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new file just for the lock image and use it wherever you want.

Something like this:

#### File *LockImage.qml*

```
Item {
    property bool locked: false
    Image {
        id: lcked
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        source: locked? "Images/Locked.png": "Images/Unlocked.png"
        visible: true
    }
}
```

Side note: you don’t need to change properties using clicked handler. Prefer using the checked property of `Button`